# Wiki markup to confluence page using Python

Tags: python, request, confluence, wiki-markup

Currently I have 'n' URLs written in wiki markup language and now I need to migrate the webpage to Confluence.
I am able to create a Confluence page using python (pyconfluence), and add up whatever text I want to write.
Using  `request` module, I am able to get the HTML content of the wiki page. 
Is there any means or better suggestion through which I can copy the contents of the wiki page and write it to Confluence page?
Note: The wiki page has list `<li>` items and `<img>` images which I need to persist while creating the Confluence page.